Webpack React define number of chunks
I'm trying to figure out how i can explicit create chunks for some modules with webpack.
"webpack": "^5.93.0",
I use the package react-apexcharts in my app.
import { Chart } from "react-apexcharts";

First i used LimitChunkCountPlugin to pack everything in one file, but the file size is a little big.
new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1,
    }),

so i tried it with a maxChunk size of 5 for testing and added an optimization part:
    optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            apexcharts: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/](react-apexcharts)[\\/]/,
                name: "apexcharts",
                chunks: "all",
                enforce: true, // Force creation
            },
        },
    },
},

But the chunk is not created. Only if i delete the LimitChunkCountPlugin part it gets created, but with several other chunks for other packages.
Is there a way to achieve that only the react-apexcharts get chunked?
